# What should I do to test the confidence of my deep learning model?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, classification, statistics

I've recently fine-tuned a deep learning framework/model BERT for a sentiment classification task. I had a 80/10/10 train/validation and test set. After running several experiments, I've gotten a decent model that I'd like to eventually productionize. However, I'm looking to create an experiment to test the robustness/reliability/confidence of the model before putting it into production. **What are some ways/experiments that can be conducted to test the robustness/reliability/confidence of this model or its predictions?**

For example, are there statistically sound principles behind calculating the standard error for binary predictions on a new datapoint?

Comment: Bootstrap the metric you are optimising for and build confidence intervals around it.

Answer (score 1):

For binary predictions, it is standard to evaluate models based on their [ROC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic) and [PRC](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/precision-recall-curve-ml/) curves. Some metrics are also useful, namely [MCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matthews_correlation_coefficient), which is probably the most holistic scalar metric.

Using these metrics, you should evaluate the model via [cross-validation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)). For deep models that take significant time to train, k-fold cross-validation is often sufficient. If you want, you can also do repeated k-fold cross validation, if time permits.

Lastly, while not always possible, many consider the use of different datasets to be one of the best indicators of reliability. Splitting a single dataset still risks "leaking" a common bias in both the training and testing sets. When using two or more datasets, biases that the model learns in the training dataset probably wouldn't manifest in a completely different dataset, hence a more objective evaluation methodology that mimics a production environment. Such biases include, among many things, data acquisition methods, preprocessing/data cleaning methods, etc..

Comment: hey Benji,
Thank you for your input. I am aware of ROC, PRC & MCC as other evaluation metrics that I can use to select models. However, given a model that I've already selected based on either of those evaluation metrics, I'd like to further test the robustness/confidence of the models. Like for example in OLS, we can use prediction intervals to get a confidence of the predicted output. Is there something similar for binary classification?

Comment: hey misheekoh, Thanks for the question. I have never come across a method which does statistical testing. You may create a more robust validation strategy by doing Out of time validation also. Also you can introduce some noise to see how model behaves with small changes to input.